# Using views to generate Menu items?

Tags: views, routes, taxonomy-terms

I would like to use the filtering option of views to generate menu item from a **common tag** to **2 different taxonomies**.

For exemple I have 2 differents **content type** "**Story**" and "**tutorial**" each of them have the **tag "potatoes"**.

I would like a **menu item** that **link to** all the **stories about potatoes** and another to all the **tutorial about potatoes**.

I was thinking of using views for that but there is no "**display format: Menu Item**" so i'm stuck.

help please

Comment: Can't you use the HTML- or Unformatted list and display them in a block?

Comment: I would like to display them in the Main menu in order to integrate it to my TB MegaMenu.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://drupal.org/project/menu_views

Comment: this module could have been perfect but unfortunatly it is incomptaible with TB megamenu :(